# Moen water faucet spins, stops spin

Tags: faucet

The Moen faucets work to adjust water flow and do not leak. I have taken the handle and plastic spline off. After meeting some resistance, the stops spin. How do I tighten the stops on a Moen 2 handle faucet?

Comment: does Moen make only one model of two handle faucet?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you (e.g the faucet model and a picture). And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.